# Trying to set add form without refreshing a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying with JS make my form for comments without refreshing a page. I dont know what to do, because there is no errors but when I add something it doesnt work well I need to refresh a page to see changes.

show.html.erb

```
...
<table id="comments">
  <tbody>
    <% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
...
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><p><%= comment.name %></p></td>
  <td><p><%= comment.body %></p></td>
  <td><p><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p></td>
  <% if User.find_by(email: comment.name) == current_user %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.article, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  <% else %>
    <td> </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

create.js.erb

```
$('table#comments tbody').append("<%= j render @comment %>")
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'search/index'

  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  get '/search', to: 'search#search'



  resources :user
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
    member do
      put "like" => "articles#like"
      put "unlike" => "articles#unlike"
    end
  end
  resources :search, only: [:index]

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: You say there's no error but there should be some information both on the rails log and on the browser's network tab. You can also add a `debugger;` line on your `create.js.erb` view so it will stop execution when you render that view so you can debug what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different to debug issue, first of all check your web browser console what are you getting, any error message. You have also not put your controller to checks its code too. I will do following to check issue. Start server and load that page and in console I will write following

```
$('table#comments tbody').append("This is just test")
```

I will check if any change came to my page, as it should have this sentence, so that mean I am hitting proper place. Now try following command to see if it works

```
$('table#comments tbody').append("<%= escape_javascript(render @comment) %>")
```

If you still have issue than you have to check your action, and does it respond back to JS.